# Intermittent Axios delete 404 error but always deleting from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, axios

My Axios delete function below is catching a 404 error intermittently even though it is always deleting from the database.

```
const api = "http://localhost:4000/api/message";

export const deleteMessage = (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios
      .delete(`${api}/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(deleteMessageSuccess(id));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
};
```

Here is my route for delete

```
const express = require("express");

const MovieCtrl = require("../controllers/message-ctrl");

const router = express.Router();

router.delete("/message/:id", MovieCtrl.deleteMessage);
```

Here is my controller js express code.

```
deleteMessage = async (req, res) => {
  await Message.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, message) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err });
    }

    if (!message) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ success: false, error: `The Abyss cannot find your message!` });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: message });
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Here is the error.

```
xhr.js:178 DELETE http://localhost:3001/api/message/5f0348c849a04a0e71e732e2 404 (Not Found)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

Here is my express index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const db = require("./data/db");
const messageRouter = require("./routes/message-router");

const app = express();
const apiPort = 4000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.use("/api", messageRouter);

app.listen(apiPort, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${apiPort}`));
```

I've tried sending the id as a param instead of including it in the API URL but that did not change anything. I do notice that when the Axios delete call fails with the 404 error the err & message callback parameters on the findOneAndDelete function in my controller are null but the req & res parameters are still being correctly passed. I've only found a couple of similar issues online but none of the solutions applied to my code, I would love some help. :)

EDIT: When I remove the if (!message) block in the controller the error goes away even though a console.log(message) will return null sometimes still.

Comment: what does `console.log(message)` print?

Comment: it prints null when I get the error and the message when I don't get the error.
ie.
{
  _id: 5f034dbf15b13a0fc6b353d1,
  message: 'dsfsf',
  wordcount: 1,
  createdAt: 2020-07-06T16:13:51.930Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-07-06T16:13:51.930Z,
  __v: 0
}

Comment: `Message.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, message) => {` are you sure that `(err, message)` is the right order inside your function? Maybe the function works fine, but you mixed up an error with a message?

Comment: I do believe that is the order MongoDB uses for callbacks